# Using C# with selenium and cleditor

Tags: c#, selenium, cleditor

I want to be able to set the body for a cleditor text field using selenium in c#, but this process seems to be very difficult. Can anyone explain it like i'm 4 years old?

Comment: By setting body, do you mean entering text?

Comment: yeah, its being used as an email constructor, and then the entered text will be sent in the email

Comment: Which Selenium do you use? Web Driver or RC?

Comment: What have you tried? How did that not work? Any errors? If so, what were they? What does the HTML markup look like? What browser? What version of that browser? What version of Selenium? When you say 'difficult', what is 'difficult' exactly?

Comment: I have tried to find the Editor using selenium (FindElement By CssSelector), and it claims the element cannot be found. The html looks like a cl text editor, which if you're curious, you can find [here](http://premiumsoftware.net/CLEditor). firefox, newest, and its difficult becasue i can't do it.

Web Driver

Comment: The editor has a few embedded IFrames, this is proved by just opening it in Chrome's Developer tools - thus I'd advise you to look up how to use Selenium to navigate between IFrames. The calls you are making are probably fine, but they are not being navigated to the actual *child* IFrame that contains the elements.  http://assertselenium.com/2013/02/22/handling-iframes-using-webdriver/     ..... https://www.google.co.uk/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=iframes+selenium

Answer (score 1):

The basic Selenium logic is you find the element first, then perform actions to it.

However, in this case, you have the following difficulties:

1. the editor is in an `iframe`
2. the iframe doesn't have id, name or even meaningful src
3. the editor is not an input or textarea, but the `body` itself.

**How to navigate into iframes** (Arran's link should be a good tutorial to look at)

Use Firefox+Firebug+Firepath to find iframes.

[image: Firefox+Firebug+Firepath usage]

As you can see, there are four iframes in the page, you need one of the following methods to switch to the editor frame, not the other frames. ([source](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver/ITargetLocator.cs))

```
IWebDriver Frame(int frameIndex); // works but not desirable, as you have 4 frames, index might be changing
IWebDriver Frame(string frameName); // not working, your editor doesn't have frameName or id.
IWebDriver Frame(IWebElement frameElement); // the way to go, find frame by xpath or css selector in your case
```

So we have:

```
IWebElement iframe = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@src='javascript:true;']"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);
```

**How to send keys to the editor**

Once your driver is inside the iframe, through Firebug, you can see that the editor is actually the `body`, not `input` or `textarea`.

So you need to find the body element, clear it and send keys. Note that `Clear()` may not work on body element, so you need either use `IJavaScriptExecutor` or send `Control+a` to select all first.

**Switch out of the iframes**

After some text has been sent to the editor, you can use `driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();` to get out.

**The completed code**

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace SOTest {
    [TestClass]
    public class TestCLEditor {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1() {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://premiumsoftware.net/CLEditor");

            // find frames by src like 'javascript:true;' is really not a good idea, but works in this case
            IWebElement iframe = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@src='javascript:true;']"));
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);

            IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")); // then you find the body
            body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a"); // send 'ctrl+a' to select all
            body.SendKeys("Some text");

            // alternative way to send keys to body
            // IJavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            // jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; body.innerHTML = 'Some text';");

            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In google chrome navigate to the page right click on the editable area of the text field. Click Inspect Element. When the html opens up, right click on the highlighted element and click Copy XPath.

In Selenium Web driver

```
IWebElement textField =      driver.FindElement(By.XPath("Paste what you got from CHROME"));
textField.SendKeys("Desired Text");
```